# $48$ balls, draw $6$ balls, how many bets are needed to ensure that exactly $1$ ball matches in at least $1$ bet?

Tags: probability, combinations

I have a method to calculate it. But it does not make sense. So most likely I misinterpret the numbers. Please show me from where it goes south.

### The rule

This is a simplified version of the lottery game.

There are $48$ balls with numbers $1$ to $48$. $6$ balls are drawn to make up the winning combination. A betting combination is also $6$ balls.

### My approach

Choosing $6$ balls from $48$ balls, there are totally $\binom{48}6 = 12,271,512$ combinations.

For a bet, to have exactly 1 ball matches, first choose $1$ from the $6$ winning balls, then choose $5$ from the rest balls. So there are $\binom 61\times \binom {48-6}5 = 5,104,008$ combinations having exactly $1$ ball matches.

The probability of my bet having exactly $1$ ball matches will be $\frac{5,104,008}{12,271,512} = 0.4159233189846532$.

I am quite sure the above probability is correctly calculated.

### The Confusion

As above, the probably of $1$ bet having exactly $1$ ball matches is $0.4159233189846532$.

If I buy $2$ bets, the probably of having at least $1$ bet that has exactly $1$ ball matches will be $0.4159233189846532\times2 = 0.8318466379693065$.

If I buy $3$ bets, the probably of having at least $1$ bet that has exactly $1$ ball matches will be $0.4159233189846532 \times 3 = 1.24776995695396$.

It is bigger than $1$, which means it must occur. However, let's say the winning combination is $(1,2,3,4,5,6)$. If we buy $3$ bets, which can be $(7,8,9,10,11,12) (13,14,15,16,17,18)$ and $(19,20,21,22,23,24)$. There are no bets having exactly $1$ matches.

There are totally $48$ balls. it can be separated into $8 (= 48 / 6)$ different combinations that I must have at least one bet having at least one match. I understand "at least one match" is different from "exactly one match" though.

### The Question

How many bets are needed to ensure having at least $1$ bet that has exactly $1$ ball matches? How to calculate, and which part of my attempt is incorrect?

Comment: The title doesn't fit the question. You seem to be interested in the number of bets, not the number of draws.

Comment: Yes you are right. But they are the same, isn't it?

Comment: No they aren't. In most lotteries there are millions placing bets, but only one draw. If it were the other way around, the lottery organisere would be making a loss.

Comment: No, they're not. No finite number of draws could guarantee that you ever have exactly one ball matching, unless you have enough bets to guarantee it for a single draw anyway, since the draw could be the same every time.

Comment: Another confusion: the probability some event will be produced when placing two bets is not the double of the probability that the event will happen when placing one bet.  As is correctly observed, such reasoning would lead to probabilities greater than $1$, which are always wrong.

Comment: Hmm... what if we see it in this way. There are total 12M combinations. There is 1 combination that is the winning one. How many combinations out of 12M are having exactly 1 match with the winning one? This is what I shown in the "My approach" part. Is that probability and understanding correct?

Comment: Yes I agree probability greater than 1 is weird.

Comment: By the way, if changing the requirement to "having at least 1 match", as the last paragraph says, it is clearly if I place 8 bets wisely, I must get at least 1 bet that has at least 1 match. But how to calculate (instead of think) the answer 8?

Comment: In this other problem you need not _calculate_ the number, you may guess it, and then prove it is correct. To prove it correct you prove that the number is at most $8$ (because you have a solution with $8$ bets that works) and prove that it cannot be less than $8$ (because given any $\leq7$ bets, you can find a draw where none of them have any match).

Comment: "Guess" cannot be generalized. If the requirement is "having at least 2 matches" or even "having at least 4 matches (which is like the 3rd prize of the lottery)", it become almost impossible to "guess".

Answer (score 2):

I am going to call $p$ the probability of a desired combination being drawn: that is, a combination of 6 balls with exactly one match. You already calculated that probability.

Now, if I buy $n$ tickets, what is the probability of at least one of them being such a combination?

It is $1-\Bbb{P}(\text{none of them are})$. The probability of none of them being a desired combination is of course $(1-p)^n$, therefore the final answer is:
$$ 1-(1-p)^n $$

Keep in mind that you should never ever get a probability greater than one (or less than zero) even for certain or impossible events.

Now, let's find an optimal combination of bets to guarantee that at least one bet contains at least one matching ball.

First of all, we cannot leave 6 or more numbers uncovered by our bets: otherwise, the drawn combination could be exactly those 6, and we would lose.

Therefore we need to cover at least 43 different numbers, which we can do with no less than 8 tickets. These are enough to cover the whole range of balls, and thus ensures our victory.

Comment: Great answer! This clears most of the mist. I would suggest calling it the "desired" combination, instead of the term "winning" which might be misleading.

Comment: @midnite Ah, right, that would be better.

Comment: Hold on: I realized I misunderstood the last part of your question. Let me get to my desk and figure this out.

Comment: Thanks again. May I know how to generalise the second part of your answer? In another words, what is the equation to find *an optimal numbers of bets to guarantee that at least one bet contains at least N matching balls*? For N=1, it's easy to "think". For N=2, it seems so hard already.

Comment: @midnite Just think in terms of pairs, and cover all pairs with the least number of bets: a quick idea is that you have 48*47/2 pairs and each bet covers 3...

Comment: ... only 2 pairs (4 balls) can be uncovered. So we have to cover 48*47/2-2 pairs. This needs CEILING( (48*47/2 -2)*2 /6 ) bets. Is this correct?

Comment: @midnite That many is definitely enough, the hard part is showing you can't use any less...